# Merge two lists, replacing elements with same index in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like to replace elements in one list with elements in another, but only as far as the second list goes.

For example:

```py
defaults = ['apple','banana','cherry','date']
data = ['accordion','banjo']

#   result: ['accordion','banjo','cherry','date']
```

I can do it with a `for` loop, and I can do it in one line with the following code:

```py
result = [data[i] if i<len(data) else defaults[i] for i,v in enumerate(defaults)]
```

Is there a simpler or more direct approach to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
result = data + defaults[len(data):]
```

If `data` can be longer than `defaults` and you want the length of `defaults` to be the maximum length:

```
result = data[:len(defaults)] + defaults[len(data):]
```

This use of `:` is called 'slicing', more on slicing lists here [python.org on Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)